# webservice in class library Host Error

Tags: c#, web-services

this is my first project in developing web service. 
Its existing application. My project is classlibrary ..to this we added webservice.svc..

To see webservice wsdl ..what are the steps..? how to publish service in IIS.
please can anyone suggest me..

when i publish website i should publish as web deploy?

i tried to publish as webdeploy.. before that i created web site in IIS and tried to publish to hosted site in IIS ..publish succeed.. when i browse the service am getting below error, what does it mean..please help me..

**provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.**

copied my web config file..

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue. Service Host service name not matching.. i tried to add test WCh service and compare .svc file..

fixed and running in IIS to..